# I have xml data in a clob and I am trying to pull the data using PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xquery

I have a XML stored in table test with column type as FILE_DATA

This is one of the sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
<File_Data>
<Detail_Supplier>
<Detail SUPPLIER="ABC" NAME="ABC" REGISTRATION="N/A" COUNTRY="UNITED STATES" ACCOUNT_TYPE="XYZ" NUMBER="123" ID="1" DATE="2022-02-10T00:00:00" REG_NUMBER="412" STATUS="Sent" />
<Detail SUPPLIER="ABC" NAME="ABC" REGISTRATION="N/A" COUNTRY="UNITED STATES" ACCOUNT_TYPE="XYZ" NUMBER="456" ID="1" DATE="2022-02-10T00:00:00" REG_NUMBER="418" STATUS="Sent" />
</Detail_Supplier>
</File_Data>
</File>
```

I need 'Number', 'REG_NUMBER','STATUS' from both Detail tags

Below is the script I am trying to pull the data

```
SELECT y.*
      FROM test,
           XMLTABLE ('/File/File_Data/Detail_Supplier/Detail' PASSING XMLTYPE (getvalue_clob_post (FILE_DATA))
COLUMNS "NUMBER" VARCHAR2 (500) PATH 'NUMBER',
 "REG_NUMBER" VARCHAR2 (500) PATH 'REG_NUMBER',
"STATUS" VARCHAR2 (500) PATH 'STATUS') y
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS version.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, you just need to use `@` to reference an XML attribute. And no need to use `getvalue_clob_post()` function.

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=89de1198a0f16db292fe75a043d1850f)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE HOLDS_XML
        (xml_col CLOB);

INSERT INTO HOLDS_XML (xml_col)
VALUES ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File xsi:schemaLocation="Supplier_x0020_TN reports.obexchange.com" Name="Supplier Report" 
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Supplier_x0020_TN">
    <File_Data>
        <Detail_Supplier>
            <Detail SUPPLIER="ABC" NAME="ABC" REGISTRATION="N/A" COUNTRY="UNITED STATES" ACCOUNT_TYPE="XYZ" NUMBER="123" ID="1" DATE="2022-02-10T00:00:00" REG_NUMBER="412" STATUS="Sent"/>
            <Detail SUPPLIER="ABC" NAME="ABC" REGISTRATION="N/A" COUNTRY="UNITED STATES" ACCOUNT_TYPE="XYZ" NUMBER="456" ID="1" DATE="2022-02-10T00:00:00" REG_NUMBER="418" STATUS="Sent"/>
        </Detail_Supplier>
    </File_Data>
</File>');

SELECT y.*
      FROM HOLDS_XML,
           XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces(default 'Supplier_x0020_TN'),
           '/File/File_Data/Detail_Supplier/Detail' 
           PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_col)
COLUMNS "NUMBER" VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@NUMBER',
      REG_NUMBER VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@REG_NUMBER',
          STATUS VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@STATUS') y;
```

**SQL #2**

When namespaces are 'dynamic', it is possible to use namespace wildcards.

```
SELECT y.*
      FROM HOLDS_XML,
           XMLTABLE (
           '/*:File/*:File_Data/*:Detail_Supplier/*:Detail' 
           PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_col)
COLUMNS "NUMBER" VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@NUMBER',
      REG_NUMBER VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@REG_NUMBER',
          STATUS VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@STATUS') y;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+------------+--------+
| NUMBER | REG_NUMBER | STATUS |
+--------+------------+--------+
|    123 |        412 | Sent   |
|    456 |        418 | Sent   |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you ! it worked,

In xml file after 'File' I have some namespace and special characters, how to avoid those lines and read only which is required

for example 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File xsi:schemaLocation="Supplier_x0020_TN https://reports.obexchange.com/" Name="Supplier Report" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Supplier_x0020_TN">

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment under your question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example: ##1-4. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: I updated the answer to accommodate namespaces. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, It is not working, I am copying the exactly which is available in my file, when I am trying to run as you mentioned I ma unable to see the output.

Comment: <File xsi:schemaLocation="Invoice_x0020_Reconciliation_x0020_Report_x0020_by_x0020_Supplier_x0020_TN https://reports.obexchange.com/ReportServer?%2FSupport%2FSSDM%20-%20%20Reports%2FInvoice%20Reconciliation%20Report%20by%20Supplier%20TN&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="Invoice Reconciliation Report by Supplier TN" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Invoice_x0020_Reconciliation_x0020_Report_x0020_by_x0020_Supplier_x0020_TN">

Comment: SELECT y.*
      FROM HOLDS_XML,
           XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces(default 'Invoice_x0020_TN'),
           '/File/File_Data/Detail_Supplier/Detail' 
           PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_col)
COLUMNS "NUMBER" VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@NUMBER',
    REG_NUMBER VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@REG_NUMBER',
        STATUS VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@STATUS') y;   -- it is not working

Comment: the value in the namespace is not constant, as of now it is hardcoded, but it will keep on changing, so how to handle if the value is not constant

Comment: No need to use comments for XML and code. You need to edit your original question for that.

Comment: @Santosh, I updated the answer with the SQL #2. Check it out.